# Java casting between two presumably unrelated classes

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to understand how the java compiler works regarding type casting but I can't figure it out.

please see the following code

```
    public class SampleTester{
    public static interface A1{}
    public static class A2{}
    public static class A3 extends A2 implements A1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            List<A1> test = new ArrayList<>();
            test.add(new A3());
            A2 a2 = (A2) test.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

this code compiles, but if I change

```
A2 a2 = (A2) test.get(0);
```

to

```
A2 a2 = (Integer) test.get(0);
```

It gives a compilation error.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to SampleTester.A2

as I see it, A2 is not related to A1 in any way (exactly as the integer isn't related), so how come the cast work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the title of your question is incorrect - you are not casting between two classes - you are casting an expression whose type is an interface type to a class type.

`test.get(0)` is of type `A1`, an interface. Even though `A2` doesn't implement that interface, some sub-class of `A2` may implement the interface (and actually you defined such a class - `A3`), so the cast can succeed. Therefore the compiler allows it.

`Integer` cannot be sub-classed (it's a final class), so there won't ever be a sub-class of `Integer` that implements `A1`. Since the cast can never succeed, the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: great answer, thanks. after your answer I realized that even after taking "extends A2" it compiles, meaning (correct me if I'm wrong) the compiler doesn't need to see a true hierarchy connection, just a potential of one.